# How to set Jenkins job to Failure on specific word in console?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, pipeline

Hello Guys i want to know if there is any function to set Jenkins job to Failure on specific word in console .
for example I have a successful Job, but it has a message log in Warning and I want to stop it when he sees this message other than that I want him to work well

Comment: Have a look at [Warnings Next Generation plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/).

Comment: Use the [Text Finder Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/text-finder/), it is exactly what you are looking for; And it supports both files and the console log.